# Change input values based on another input r shiny

Tags: r, events, shiny, reactive

In the server function I have `observe` sinppet in which the plot and datatable output dependent variables are there which filter the data based on input variables.

Now the output plot and datatable are working fine and as expected but I want the other dropdown inputs to react when I change any value in any other pickerinputs.

If I include renderUI in the `observe` then everything breaks since at initialization every other input is null so filter data returns No records.

Do I have to write `observeEvent` function for each input and update every other input? or there is another way to do it?

In the end I want the pickerinputs to work like slicers in Excel.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observe({

#filter data
bData <- dplyr::filter(bData, Crncy %in% input$selCrncy)
bData <- dplyr::filter(bData, bData$`AXE?` %in% input$selAxe)
bData <- dplyr::filter(bData, bData$`Owned?` %in% input$selOwned)
bData <- dplyr::filter(bData, bData$Floater %in% input$selFloater)
bData <- dplyr::filter(bData, bData$`Collateral Type` %in% input$selCollateralType)
bData <- dplyr::filter(bData, bData$`Maturity Type` %in% input$selMaturityType)
bData <- dplyr::filter(bData, bData$`Issuer Name` %in% input$selIssuerName)
bData <- dplyr::filter(bData, bData$Sector %in% input$selSector)
bData <- subset(bData, bData$MatYear >= input$dtrng[1] &  bData$MatYear <= input$dtrng[2])



 #Scatter Plot
    output$OPlot<-renderPlotly({
      
      p <- plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers', 
              color = ~Crncy, colors = setNames(rainbow(nrow(bData)), bData$Crncy),
              marker = list(opacity = 0.7, size=12) ,
              text = ~paste(" Security: ", bData$Security, "<br>",
                            "Currency: ", bData$Crncy, "<br>",
                            "YTM: ", bData$YTM,"<br>",
                            "DM: ", bData$DM)) %>% 
        layout(xaxis = list(title="Maturity"), 
               yaxis = list(title="FRN: DM | Fixed: YAS ASW USD")) %>% 
        add_markers(symbol = ~factor(bData$Sym),color = I("black"), marker = list( opacity = 1, size=6))
      
        
        #add_markers(symbol = ~factor(bData$Sym),symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open'),color = I("black"), marker = list( opacity = 1, size=9))

    })
    
    #Data table output
    output$datatbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      bData,
      options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
    )
    
    
  })
  

  output$dateUIOP <- renderUI({

    sliderInput("dtrng", "Year Range:",
                min=min(bData$MatYear), max=max(bData$MatYear),
                value = c(min(bData$MatYear),max=max(bData$MatYear))
                )
  
  })
  
  output$selCrncyUIOP <- renderUI({
    
    pickerInput("selCrncy","Currency", choices=unique(bData$Crncy),
                selected = unique(bData$Crncy),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)
    
  })
  
  output$selAxeUIOP <- renderUI({
    
    pickerInput("selAxe","Axe?", choices=unique(bData$`AXE?`),
                selected = unique(bData$`AXE?`),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)
    
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The OP said they want Excel-style slicers, which are also like List Boxes in QlikView.  These allow the user to filter data that appears in the rest of the app, but also react to the selections from other filters.  I thought it was an interesting challenge and so I made the following prototype.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

my_mpg <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(across(c(manufacturer, class, cyl), ~factor(., ordered = TRUE)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, reactableOutput("manufacturer_slicer")),
    column(4, reactableOutput("class_slicer")),
    column(4, reactableOutput("cyl_slicer"))
  ),
    plotOutput("scatterplot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  user_selections <- reactiveValues(manufacturer = levels(my_mpg$manufacturer),
                                    class = levels(my_mpg$class),
                                    cyl = levels(my_mpg$cyl))
  
  output$manufacturer_slicer <- renderReactable({
    my_mpg %>% 
      group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
      summarize(`# Rows` = n(),
                `Total cty` = sum(cty), .groups = "drop") %>% 
      arrange(manufacturer) %>% 
      reactable(sortable = TRUE, searchable = TRUE, compact = TRUE, highlight = TRUE,
                selection = "multiple", onClick = "select", defaultSelected = 1:length(levels(my_mpg$manufacturer)))
  })
  
  output$class_slicer <- renderReactable({
    my_mpg %>% 
      group_by(class) %>% 
      summarize(`# Rows` = n(),
                `Total cty` = sum(cty), .groups = "drop") %>% 
      reactable(sortable = TRUE, searchable = TRUE, compact = TRUE, highlight = TRUE,
                selection = "multiple", onClick = "select", defaultSelected = 1:length(levels(my_mpg$class)))
  })
  
  output$cyl_slicer <- renderReactable({
    my_mpg %>% 
      group_by(cyl) %>% 
      summarize(`# Rows` = n(),
                `Total cty` = sum(cty), .groups = "drop") %>% 
      reactable(sortable = TRUE, searchable = TRUE, compact = TRUE, highlight = TRUE,
                selection = "multiple", onClick = "select", defaultSelected = 1:length(levels(my_mpg$cyl)))
  })
  
  observeEvent(getReactableState("manufacturer_slicer", "selected"), priority = 20, {
    user_selections$manufacturer <- levels(my_mpg$manufacturer)[getReactableState("manufacturer_slicer", "selected")]
  })
  
  observeEvent(getReactableState("class_slicer", "selected"), priority = 20, {
    user_selections$class <- levels(my_mpg$class)[getReactableState("class_slicer", "selected")]
  })
  
  observeEvent(getReactableState("cyl_slicer", "selected"), priority = 20, {
    user_selections$cyl <- levels(my_mpg$cyl)[getReactableState("cyl_slicer", "selected")]
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    my_mpg %>% 
      filter(manufacturer %in% user_selections$manufacturer,
             class %in% user_selections$class,
             cyl %in% user_selections$cyl)
  })
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    filtered_data() %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=displ, y = hwy)) +
      geom_point()
  })
  
  observeEvent(filtered_data(), priority = 10, {
    req(filtered_data())
    
    new_manufacturer_data <- filtered_data() %>% 
      group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
      summarize(`# Rows` = n(),
                `Total cty` = sum(cty), .groups = "drop") %>% 
      complete(manufacturer, fill = list(`# Rows` = 0, `Total cty` = 0)) %>% 
      arrange(manufacturer)
    
    new_manufacturer_selected <- which(new_manufacturer_data$manufacturer %in% user_selections$manufacturer)
    
    new_manufacturer_page = getReactableState("manufacturer_slicer", "page")
    
    new_class_data <- filtered_data() %>% 
      group_by(class) %>% 
      summarize(`# Rows` = n(),
                `Total cty` = sum(cty), .groups = "drop") %>% 
      complete(class, fill = list(`# Rows` = 0, `Total cty` = 0)) %>% 
      arrange(class)
    
    new_class_selected <- which(new_class_data$class %in% user_selections$class)
    
    new_class_page = getReactableState("class_slicer", "page")
    
    new_cyl_data <- filtered_data() %>% 
      group_by(cyl) %>% 
      summarize(`# Rows` = n(),
                `Total cty` = sum(cty), .groups = "drop") %>% 
      complete(cyl, fill = list(`# Rows` = 0, `Total cty` = 0)) %>% 
      arrange(cyl)
    
    new_cyl_selected <- which(new_cyl_data$cyl %in% user_selections$cyl)
    
    new_cyl_page = getReactableState("cyl_slicer", "page")
    
    updateReactable("manufacturer_slicer", data = new_manufacturer_data, selected = new_manufacturer_selected, page = new_manufacturer_page)
    updateReactable("class_slicer", data = new_class_data, selected = new_class_selected, page = new_class_page)
    updateReactable("cyl_slicer", data = new_cyl_data, selected = new_cyl_selected, page = new_cyl_page)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

One problem with this kind of situation is the circular logic that can cause an endless cascade of reactions.  I save the user's selections in a `reactiveValues` to break the chain.  I use `observeEvent` to first update the saved selections in the `user_selections` object, and then to update the slicer UI elements.  The `priority` setting ensures the user's choices are saved before doing any updates.

The slicers can contain statistics from the data that tell the user about the relevance of the different column values in the context of the current filtering.  These should change based on the business logic.  The `# Rows` tells the user if that value appears in the filtered data.

I use ordered factors for the columns because I'm worried about problems from the fact that `reactable` refers to row indices, not the values themselves.

I'm not happy with the amount of copy-and-paste boilerplate, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `reactive()` and not `observe()` to filter your data.  Use `req()` to silently stop the reactive from giving an error before the input pickers are ready.

```
filtered_data <- reactive({
    req(input$selCrncy, input$selAxe, input$selOwned, input$selFloater, input$selCollateralType, input$selMaturityType, input$selIssuerName, input$selSector, input$dtrng)
    bData %>% 
        filter(Crncy %in% input$selCrncy,
               bData$`AXE?` %in% input$selAxe,
               bData$`Owned?` %in% input$selOwned,
               bData$Floater %in% input$selFloater,
               bData$`Collateral Type` %in% input$selCollateralType,
               bData$`Maturity Type` %in% input$selMaturityType,
               bData$`Issuer Name` %in% input$selIssuerName,
               bData$Sector %in% input$selSector,
               bData$MatYear >= input$dtrng[1],
               bData$MatYear <= input$dtrng[2])
})

output$datatbl = DT::renderDataTable(
    filtered_data(),
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
)
```

Also use `data = filtered_data()` instead of `data = bData` in the `renderPlotly` command.

I'm not sure exactly how you want the pickers to change based on other pickers, but `renderUI` is definitely the way to do it.  If you want a picker to depend on another picker, use `req()` to stop it from rendering until the other one is ready.

Comment: Basically what I want is if I select let say maturity year 2024 to 2027 then all the other picker should update based on filtered data also they should not lose the selected values when updating the inputs. 

Similar to slicers in excel dashboards.

Comment: This is much more complicated than I realized.  There are two difficulties.  The first is working out the reactivity logic.  This can be handled.  The second is that the pickerInput (or any shiny input that I know of) is not up to the task.  The pickerInput can only show selected/not-selected.  But the slicer needs to also indicate which choices appear/don't-appear in the data.  Shiny is much stronger in showing tables and ggplots that react to the user's input.  I would use an output, not an input, to show the dimensions that are appearing in the filtered data.

Comment: If someone wanted to build an Excel-style slicer, they could do it with either a ggplot output or a table-like output, such as DT or Reactable.  These can respond to a user's clicks and dynamically update their order and color.  Making this would be very interesting, but non-trivial.  Personally I would use a table-like object, especially because you could also add columns of data (like number of rows, or sums of important columns) that respond to the filtering of all such objects.