# Multiple bidirectional filters of various data types in Shiny as in Power BI

Tags: r, shiny, powerbi

I am developing a Shiny app that includes several mutually dependent (i.e. bidirectional) filters of several data types (e.g. character, numeric, date). I would like the values of each filter to update on the fly based on the selections in other filters, regardless of the order in which a user applies the filters.

I am able to easily achieve this in Power BI, which I am more familiar with, and an example of the desired functionality is shown in the following gif:

[image]

So far, I have been unable to replicate this functionality in a Shiny app. I have explored [`datamods::select_group_ui()`](https://dreamrs.github.io/datamods/reference/select-group.html) which allows for auto-updating filter values, but only works for filtering character values. A function from the same package, [`filter_data_ui()`](https://dreamrs.github.io/datamods/reference/filter-data.html), allows for connecting filters of various data types, but the values do not update in response to user inputs in other filters.

I have also played with `updateSelectInput()` and `renderUI()` as discussed in the following Stackoverflow threads, but to no avail:

- [Change input values based on another input r shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958556/change-input-values-based-on-another-input-r-shiny)
- [Shiny: Automatic SelectInput Value Update Based on Previous Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348193/shiny-automatic-selectinput-value-update-based-on-previous-filter)
- [How to create dynamic filters in my R Shiny App to automatically update the values in 2nd filter based on the selection of value in the 1st filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74653162/how-to-create-dynamic-filters-in-my-r-shiny-app-to-automatically-update-the-valu)

Any advice or ideas would be greatly appreciated.